# in_array function (read from a file instead within the line)

Tags: php

im trying to read words from a .txt file (one word per line),
currently, i have all the words within the PHP code, but i would like to have it read from a txt file:

```
<?php $user = $_GET['user'];
    if (in_array($_GET['user'], ['User1', 'User2']))
    {
    }else
    {
    echo "You are not in the list";
    die;
    }
?>
```

TXT File should look like this:

```
User1
User2
```

What should i do to change my second line code :()

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use $data = file('path_to_file', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

Comment: $playerlist = file('spieler.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    
if (in_array($_GET['user'], $playlist))

seems like not working :/

Comment: the $_GET['user']; needs to check the .txt file, 

so test.php?user=User1 and test.php?user=User2 would be fine, while test.php?user=User3 would result in the "You are not in the list"

Answer (score 0):

try this code and tell what it shows var_dump($users);

test.php

```
<?php

$user = $_GET['user'];
$users = file('users.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

var_dump($users);

if (in_array($user, $users)) {
    echo $user;
} else {
    echo "You are not in the list";
    die;
}
```

users.txt

```
User1
User2
```

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "Niko" [1]=> string(7) "Patrick" } Niko

Comment: code work test.php?user=Niko return Niko and test.php?user=aaaa  return You are not in the list

Answer (score 0):

Php file function read [file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file)
 and line by line and return array

```
function exists($user)
{

 return (bool) in_array($user,file('users.txt'));

}

echo exists($_GET['user']); // true or false
```

For example users.txt

```
admin
Foo
moderator 
John
```

> Look at the php read file functions